# Get {X} and {Y} values for TMS service of a bounding box

Tags: google-maps, openstreetmap, tms

[In this tread](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/73946/automatically-download-and-merge-webmap-tiles-into-one-big-image) it is explained how to download and merge tiles from a XYZ maps service.

How can I find out the X and Y values of a region defined by a special bounding box, e.g. 9.477733,53.485664,9.8856,53.602995 (CSV format)?

Am I right, that these values are the same for all XYZ maps services like Google Maps and OpenStreetMap?

Thanks for your answers!

Answer (score 0):

Depends what you are trying to do. For a tile map server google and bing are not compatible with the TMS standards, You'll need to convert the values. In my case, I was using MapBox on my web app and GoogleMaps on mobile.

In my python server code I had to add an if statement that goes something like this:

```
@application.route('/your_url/<int:idx>/<int:zoom>/<int:column>/<int:row>.png')
def map_overlay(idx, zoom, column, row):
    '''Retrievs a tile from s3 using TMS style tiling
    '''

    if request.args.get('mobile') == 'true':
        row = (1 << zoom) - row - 1
```

For further info see [Converting TMS to Google/Bing/OSM](https://alastaira.wordpress.com/2011/07/06/converting-tms-tile-coordinates-to-googlebingosm-tile-coordinates/)